# jquery temporal modification of DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, this

Using jQuery, I make these changes in the DOM:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.editable').click(function() {
        var a = $(this).find('a');
        var div = $(this).find('div');
        var str = a.text();                                                      
        if ( str == "Edit" ) {
          var cadena = div.text();
          div.empty();                                                         
          div.append('<textarea class="span10" rows="8">'+cadena+'</textarea>');
          a.html("Save");
        }
     });
  });
```

on this HTML:

```
  <div class="editable" id="ubication">                                  
     <div> test text</div>
     <a href="" >Edit</a>
  </div>
```

When I click the 'Edit' link, the textarea is inserted, but it disappears after a few seconds. How do I prevent this?

Comment: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/inerdial/GPj49/

Comment: Please revise to include a Question.

Comment: @Shad,@Pointy The problem described by the last sentence. Not very clearly but it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```
<a href="">…</a>
```

isn't a link that, when clicked, does nothing. It's a link to the current URL. The textarea doesn't disappear after a moment, the page reloads.

To fix it, use something like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">…</a>
```

I updated your example to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/inerdial/GPj49/2/

Answer (score 0):

You may use `javascript:void(0)` in link but much elegant to do preventing inside javascript code:

```
$('.editable').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxua/GPj49/3/